# Add an Django Admin page for a Managed=False model

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add a link to my Django admin page that will simply show a page with some embedded graphs from another site/app on the same server (Metabase).

I have created a metabase app that has `managed=False` so as not to create a db table. However, I can't get this to add to the admin.

Whats the best way to add this app to the admin and perhaps set it up so a default html template with my embedded iframes display ?

Thanks

Comment: `managed=False` has no relation to whether a model displays in the admin. You need to show your admin.py and any other relevant setting.

Comment: Ah. Didn't realise that. I was loading the wrong settings file. My Admin is an empty class ie

@admin.register(Metabase)
class MetabaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

The link in the admin now gives a db error SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "metabase_metabase" as the is no db table how do I override this to load a blank template ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by @daniel-roseman, there's no need to set `managed=True`. It works just as well with unmanaged models. Just make sure you did these two things:

- Register the model(s) in your app's `admin.py`, e.g. `admin.site.register(MyModel)` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects))
- Add your app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#installed-apps))

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just turned it to managed=True as the admin seems to need it.
I then redefined change_list.html